# Center large svg in container

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-position

I'm trying to center a large svg in a container div while maximizing the size of the svg and keeping the aspect ratio.

For some reason, the svg displays correctly, but the width and height attributes are incorrect, as if the svg expanded into the whole parent.

How can I make it so the svg has the right size?

Please, this should be resolved with CSS only, no javascript.

Also, note that this works if I replace the svg by a large image.

```js
var info = document.getElementById('info');
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var box = svg.getBoundingClientRect();

info.textContent = 'the ratio is ' + (box.width / box.height) + ' instead of 2.5! The yellow square is not in the viewBox, so why does it show up?';
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.svg {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg" class="svg" width="1000px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 10 5">
   <rect width="10" height="5" fill="black" />
   <rect x="-2" y="2" width="1" height="1" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="info"/>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: I believe you want to achieve the same effect as `background-size: cover`. If you don't plan on supporting old browsers and only the ever-green ones, you can try [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Comment: @Terry: no I'm trying to do object-fit: contain. Not sure how that stuff is supposed to work. As soon as I remove max-width or max-height, the svg just becomes too large

Comment: @CBroe: not sure how that helps, overflow doesn't do anything, I don't think this is the problem I'm having.

Comment: Then I don’t think I understand what problem you are actually having ... Those gray parts could only be covered if you had actual content there in your SVG image. So do you want the image to stretch to cover the whole container element width, and have parts of the image cut off on top and/or bottom, if the container is not high enough to display the whole image ... or _what_?

Comment: @CBroe: I want the svg html element to keep its aspect ratio. Here the aspect ratio is 2:1, if the container is 800x800 large, I want the svg element to have 800 width and 400 height. Here I get 800x800 in every cases, despite setting the width and height to match the 2:1 aspect ratio

Comment: @CBroe: in the example, the svg is a rectangle of size 1000px by 500px, I want to shrink to so that it fits in its container, but I want the element bounding rectangle to keep its aspect ratio. Which it doesn't do right now

Comment: @CBroe: see updated snippet, why is it that we can see the yellow box, if it's not in the viewBox?

Comment: @CBroe: are you fkg voting to close the question?! This is a legitimate question, and it's not because you don't know the answer that you should close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sense, your svg already is fitting in its container the way you want it to. In fact, most of the CSS you defined can be left off. The SVG element should be defined with `width: 100%, height: 100%`, so the `<svg>` element itself has the same size as its container. Then, the area defined by the `viewBox` is rendered into this **viewport** according to the attribute `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"`. (implicitely used, that is its default value): aspect ration preserved, maximum size that fits inside, positioned in the middle.

The problem with the yellow rect arises only because the content is clipped at the edges of the **viewport**, not the **viewBox**. So content defined in the SVG, but outside the viewBox might still be visible.

*(There initially was the idea to support a `clip` style attribute on the `<svg>` element, but its concept was so convoluted that is was unusable, it is now deprecated.)*

The best solution now is to wrap the `<svg>` element with another `<svg>`. The inner one gets absolute values for width and height, the outer one gets these same values as a viewBox and `width: 100%, height: 100%`.

As you can see, the inner svg clips the content at its edges, and the outer one fits the content into the container.

Note that you cannot define a CSS `background-color` on the inner svg. This is only defined for HTML and works on the outer one only because it is a immediate child of a HTML element. If you want a colored background, define a rect that covers the area of the viewBox with a appropriate `fill`.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

#svg1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray; /* clipped at the borders of the container! */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg1" class="svg" viewBox="0 0 10 5">
    <svg id="svg2" width="10" height="5">
      <rect width="10" height="5" fill="black" /> <!--this is your background-->
      <rect x="-2" y="2" width="1" height="1" fill="yellow" />
      <ellipse cx="5" cy="2.5" rx="6" ry="3"
               fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0.2" />
    </svg>
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="info"/>
```